# Different aov results by simply changing the name

Tags: r

I'm perfoming an fatorial aov with the following dataset: [download File](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AmwehvNnsqDFgvlbxYP-VSj6XDobWQ)

I'm reading the file with the following code:

```
Teste22 <- read.table(file.choose(),
                       header = TRUE,
                       dec = ".")
```

I'm running my aov just like that:

```
A <-as.factor(Teste22[,1])
B <-as.factor(Teste22[,2])
Rep <- as.factor(Teste22[,3])
saida<-aov(Teste22[,4]~Rep+A+B+A*B, data = Teste22)
summary(saida)
```

and get:

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Rep          1   4.03    4.03   1.032    0.324    
A            2 226.08  113.04  28.912 3.38e-06 ***
B            1   1.50    1.50   0.384    0.544    
A:B          2 243.25  121.62  31.108 2.08e-06 ***
Residuals   17  66.47    3.91
```

Notice that there is something wrong, because my Df from my blocks (Rep) is one, but my file has 4 blocks.
Now, by SIMPLY changing the name from my variable that is handling the blocks to "Bloco" the result gets right:

```
Bloco <- as.factor(Teste22[,3])
saida<-aov(Teste22[,4]~Bloco+A+B+A*B, data = Teste22)
summary(saida)
```

and get:

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Bloco        3  16.33    5.44   1.508    0.253    
A            2 226.08  113.04  31.304 4.43e-06 ***
B            1   1.50    1.50   0.415    0.529    
A:B          2 243.25  121.62  33.681 2.84e-06 ***
Residuals   15  54.17    3.61
```

Why does that happens?? I really cant figure out why only the name changed that much my results

Comment: `rep` is a function name, which may cause you issues. You should also include the output of `class(Rep)`

Comment: This is a problem as the `Rep` from the first model is using the `Rep` from the data, and not the factor you create ... hence the two models are not the same.

Comment: ... so assign the new variables to your data set (`Teste22$Rep <- as.factor(Teste22[,3])`) or remove the `data=Teste22` from the `aov`

Comment: @user20650, please post these comments as an answer ... (you might want to give an example that illustrates best practices)

Comment: @user20650 you're right! I just removed all data = Teste22 from my aov functions and solved my problem! Post as an aswer so I can vote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aov` first looks in `Teste22` for the variables passed in the formula, and uses them it they are found. If they are not in the dataset it looks in the global environment. Thus with your example, in the first model the `Rep` variable is grabbed from the `Teste22` dataset, and not the factor variable which you created, as there is a variable of the same name within `Teste22`;
it is an integer variable. The second model `Bloco` is grabbed from the 
global environment where it was created as a `factor` variable.

So a couple of things can be tidied up;
when creating factor variables it is best to assign them back to the dataset rather than creating a bunch of variables in your workspace, it is best to refer to variables by name rather than index as it makes the code clearer and reduces the likelihood of the wrong variable being used and, use the `data=` in function calls when available.

So for your example;

```
# you may wish to use `factor` to explicitely set the reference level
# which may be useful for further analysis
Teste22$Amb.SubP_f <- as.factor(Teste22$Amb.SubP.)
Teste22$Gen.Parc_f <- as.factor(Teste22$Gen.Parc.)
Teste22$Rep_f <- as.factor(Teste22$Rep)

# Note A* B expands to A + B + A:B: -- see ?`formula`
saida <- aov(Variavel1 ~ Rep_f + Amb.SubP_f* Gen.Parc_f, data=Teste22)
summary(saida)
```